# Django app + nginx fail to server static files

Tags: python, django, nginx, static

I have a verry unusual problem, none of my static files are loaded `404` is thrown. To note, I use my production environment with `DEBUG=False` set so the static files are entirely served by the `nginx` server.

> settings/production.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
DEBUG = TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False
```

> nginx/sites-enabled/myapp

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    server_name myapp.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/myapp.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/myapp.log;

    root /home/apps/myapp/;

    location / {
            gzip_static on;
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;
    }

    location /static/ { # STATIC_URL
            alias /home/apps/myapp/static/; # STATIC_ROOT
            expires 30d;
    }
    location /media/ { # MEDIA_URL
            alias /home/apps/myapp/media/; # MEDIA_ROOT
            expires 30d;
    }
}
```

> myapp.log

```
2014/04/08 04:20:11 [error] 22178#0: *590 open() "/home/apps/myapp/staticgrappelli/stylesheets/mueller/grid/output.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 77.89.196.6, server: myapp.com, request: "GET /static/grappelli/stylesheets/mueller/grid/output.css HTTP/1.1", host: "myapp.com", referrer: "http://myapp.com/admin/"
77.89.196.6 - - [08/Apr/2014:04:20:11 +0200] "GET /static/grappelli/stylesheets/mueller/grid/output.css HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "http://myapp.com/admin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36"
```

Please note that missing `/` between my static root `/home/apps/myapp/static` and application static files `grappelli/stylesheets/mueller/grid/output.css` in this example.

Does anyone have a clue regarding why this happens and how to fix it?

**UPDATE (SOLUTION)**

OK, the problem is that `Django's` static files are served by default from `www.myapp.com/static/` folder so there is no reason specifying the `/static/` folder in the `nginx` configuration file. So if anyone else has the same problem, just remove the following part from `nginx/sites-enabled/myapp` file:

```
location /static/ { # STATIC_URL
        alias /home/apps/myapp/static/; # STATIC_ROOT
            expires 30d;
        }
        location /media/ { # MEDIA_URL
            alias /home/apps/myapp/media/; # MEDIA_ROOT
            expires 30d;
        }
```

Comment: Just to clarify - myapp.log is Nginx log file?

Comment: Yes, it is the `nginx` log file. However figured it out, will post an update with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the problem is that `Django's` static files are served by default from `www.myapp.com/static/` folder so there is no reason specifying the `/static/` folder in the `nginx` configuration file. So if anyone else has the same problem, just remove the following part from `nginx/sites-enabled/myapp` file:

```
location /static/ { # STATIC_URL
        alias /home/apps/myapp/static/; # STATIC_ROOT
            expires 30d;
        }
        location /media/ { # MEDIA_URL
            alias /home/apps/myapp/media/; # MEDIA_ROOT
            expires 30d;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ran python manage.py collectstatic on your server?

Make sure the file is in the static root directory.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Make sure your main `urls.py` contains `static` & `media` routes, it should look like this:

```
$ nano /home/myuser/apps/myapp/urls.py
----
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # here goes your other routes ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

2 - Make sure `STATIC_ROOT`, `STATIC_URL`, `MEDIA_ROOT`, `MEDIA_URL` are defined in your `settings.py` :

```
$ nano `/home/myuser/apps/myapp/settings.py`
----
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

3 - Make sure your `static` and `media` paths are correct for Nginx:

```
`$ sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp`
----
# STATIC_URL
location /static/ { 
    alias /home/myuser/apps/myapp/static/;
    expires 30d;
}

# MEDIA_URL
location /media/ { 
    alias /home/myuser/apps/myapp/media/; # MEDIA_ROOT
    expires 30d;
}
```

4 - Make sure your `statics` were generated properly:

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic
```

5 - Make sure your `static` and `media` are accessible for Nginx:

```
$ cd myproject
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/myuser/apps/myapp/media/
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/myuser/apps/myapp/static/
$ sudo chmod -R 755 /home/myuser/apps/myapp/media/
$ sudo chmod -R 755 /home/myuser/apps/myapp/static/
```

6 - Restart Nginx:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Good Luck !